# R shiny how to save uioutput to a pdf file

Tags: r, pdf, download, shiny

In my Shiny app, I have a uiOutput containing a varying number of ggplots. Now I need a download button to download the uiOutput object as a pdf file.

Here I worked up a simplified piece of sample code below.

How can we edit the ??????? part of the code to make it work?

```
library(ggvis)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 = renderPlot({plot(rnorm(100))})

  output$plot2 = renderPlot({plot(rnorm(100))})

  output$table =renderTable({head(mtcars)})

  output$x = renderUI({
    div(
      plotOutput("plot1"),
      plotOutput("plot2"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  })


  output$pdflink <- downloadHandler(
    filename <- "myReport.pdf",
    content <- function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd')
      library(rmarkdown)

      out <- render('report.Rmd',pdf_document())
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  downloadButton("pdflink","Download Results")

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've had success in the past [following this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html), where you create a `.Rmd` document and use it as a template.

Comment: @Symbolix Actually I copied your code but the the browser shows "file 'report.Rmd' does not exist". I'm using windows.

Comment: you need to create a `report.Rmd`, then your shiny app will populate the `report.Rmd`

Comment: in your chunks you will have the same code that's used to create your plots in the app.

Comment: @Symbolix could you provide a sample Rmd code chunk that you used for your example. thanks.

Comment: it will be just be  ```{r} renderPlot({plot(rnorm(100))})   ```

Comment: Literally just put the code that's within an `output$plot1 <- renderPlot({` into a chunk

Comment: @Symbolix If I don't want to switch to the tmp dir and want to put the rmd file in the Shiny app folder, how to do it? The tmp dir keeps changing on my machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105316/discussion-between-symbolix-and-john).

Comment: @Symbolix Do you know what might be happening when it keeps showing "either 2 or 3 arguments are required" when I click the download button.

Comment: not off the top of my head. Is the code in the question still representative of the code you're using ?

Comment: @Symbolix Yes,it is. I have no clues where "either 2 or 3 arguments are required" come from.